# MS SQL Server How to truncate all table's rows by length?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can i perform the following operation - i need to limit all rows in table for all columns by fixed length, for only `nvarchar` typed columns.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEFT` function:

```
DECLARE @size INT = 100;

UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = LEFT(column_name, @size)
   ,column_name2 = LEFT(column_name2, @size)
...
```

where `column_nameX` is your `NVARCHAR` column.

or if you need just `SELECT`:

```
DECLARE @size INT = 100;

SELECT column_name = LEFT(column_name, @size),
      column_name2 = LEFT(column_name2, @size)
      ...
FROM  table_name
```